# How to start minikube on specific network

Tags: virtualbox, minikube

I want to start minikube cluster on specific network/`network adapter` in `VirtualBox`, so that I launch other VMs in same network like below

```
+-------+ +------+  +----------------+
|       | |      |  |                |
| VM2   | | VM1  |  | Minikube       |
|       | |      |  | Cluster        |
|       | |      |  |                |
+---+---+ +---+--+  +------------+---+
    |         |                  |
    |         |                  |
    |  +------+------------+     |
    +--+                   |     |
       |  192.168.10.0/24  +-----+
       +-------------------+
```

But I don't see much options for networking in `minikube start` [CLI](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/commands/start/)

Is it possible to start minikube like that or any trick to setup like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to **adjusting networking** with `minikube start` you can use the following option:

```
--host-only-cidr string             The CIDR to be used for the minikube VM (only supported with Virtualbox driver) (default "192.168.99.1/24")
```

As you can see in the table [here](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Network_Configuration_in_VirtualBox) by default **NAT** option doesn't give you access to `Minikube Cluster VM` neither from host nor from other guests (VMs) but you can additionally set **port forwarding** which is well described in [this](https://cwienczek.com/2017/09/reaching-minikube-from-other-devices/) article.

Although mentioned `minikube start` doesn't support many options that allow you to modify networking of your default VM, you can easily modify it by adding additional `bridged adapter` once the `Minikube VM` is created using `Virtualbox GUI` or `vboxmanage` command line tool to modify your network settings as some users suggest [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1471#issuecomment-300379543) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1471#issuecomment-390911872).

Comment: Is there any way to set static ip(`minikube ip`). I gave `--host-only-cidr 192.168.99.10/24`, but it picking other ip from pool

Comment: As far as I know there is not such option to force it to pick specific static IP from the pool but still it should be possible to change it once Minikube VM is created e.g. in /etc/network/interfaces of the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked again, the `minikube` cluster is attached to 2 networks,

1. NAT
2. Host-Only Network(`vboxnet1`)

Since it has already connected to a adapter, I can attache VM to exiting adapter and use it like below

```
+--------+            +---------------------+
|        |            |    Minikube         |
|        |            |                     |
| VM     |            |  eth1          eth0 |
|        |            |   +             +   |
|        |            +---------------------+
+---+----+                |             |
    |                     |             |
    |                     |             |
    |        +------------v------+      |
    |        |                   |      v
    +------->+   vboxnet1        |     NAT
             |   192.168.99.0/24 |
             |                   |
             +-------------------+
```

Any other suggestions are welcome